# setup basic authentication on iis7

Tags: iis-7

i have enable basic authentication for my website. but i want to use user name : "basic" and password: "ABCD1234". anyone know how can i setup username and password basic authentication on iis7.

Answer (score 1):

Setup an Windows account on the server (or a domain account if you'll have lots of web servers) with that username and password.  Make sure that Windows account has rights to the files/folders that it'll be viewing on the website.

Answer (score 0):

1. add windows user account
2. set the password never expires

open iis and go to your web site directory

1. add .net authoization rules allow your added users
2. disable anonymous authentication
3. enable basic authentication